# SQL - Update multiple records in one query

Tags: mysql, record

I have table - **config**.
Schema:
`config_name | config_value`

And I would like to update multiple records in one query. I try like that:

```
UPDATE config 
SET t1.config_value = 'value'
  , t2.config_value = 'value2' 
WHERE t1.config_name = 'name1' 
  AND t2.config_name = 'name2';
```

but that query is wrong :(

Can you help me?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL database.

Comment: Update from Select might be the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Try either multi-table update syntax

```
UPDATE config t1 JOIN config t2
    ON t1.config_name = 'name1' AND t2.config_name = 'name2'
   SET t1.config_value = 'value',
       t2.config_value = 'value2';
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84ef4/1)** demo

or conditional update

```
UPDATE config
   SET config_value = CASE config_name 
                      WHEN 'name1' THEN 'value' 
                      WHEN 'name2' THEN 'value2' 
                      ELSE config_value
                      END
 WHERE config_name IN('name1', 'name2');
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e820f/1)** demo

Comment: Yee, that's fine but what when I wolud like to update 16 records in one query? I sholud use JOIN x 16 ?

Comment: You **should** mention such important details in your question in the first place. Anyway see updated answer for another solution (conditional update).

Comment: What is t1 and t2 in your examples ?

Comment: Hello to you too @PaulBrewczynski. These are table aliases and can be written `config AS t1` where `AS` is optional.

Comment: @peterm : the SQLFiddle links are broken. Otherwise, the conditional update technique is working great. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanBenn sqlfiddle links work for me just fine.

Comment: @peterm must be my firewall or proxy then. Thx

Answer (score 201):

You can accomplish it with INSERT as below:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
(2, 'a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
(3, 'a3', 'b3', 'c3'),
(4, 'a4', 'b4', 'c4'),
(5, 'a5', 'b5', 'c5'),
(6, 'a6', 'b6', 'c6')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
a=VALUES(a),
b=VALUES(b),
c=VALUES(c);
```

This insert new values into table, but if primary key is duplicated (already inserted into table) that values you specify would be updated and same record would not be inserted second time.

Comment: a pretty smart hack. I am amazed.

Comment: Not supported for Postgres see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Comment: Also, it's a great way to turn a little bit of CSV (or a lot) into a table insert/update/upsert with some minor text editing!

Comment: hmm, tried to use this with stored procedure + table valued parameter, but I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'` error... do you perhaps know a way how to mass-update using stored procedures and table value parameter?

Comment: This is a MySQL solution, not Postgres or MSSQL.

Comment: This will increment the autoincrement id, even if the record isn't inserted or updated

Comment: Similar is possible for Postgres, using `EXCLUCED.id` - see one of below answers for details

Comment: This will fail, if we have column `d` that doesn't have a default value and is not nullable.

Answer (score 33):

in my case I have to update the records which are more than 1000, for this instead of hitting the update query each time I preferred this,

```
   UPDATE mst_users 
   SET base_id = CASE user_id 
   WHEN 78 THEN 999 
   WHEN 77 THEN 88 
   ELSE base_id END WHERE user_id IN(78, 77)
```

78,77 are the user Ids and for those user id I need to update the base_id 999 and 88 respectively.This works for me.

Comment: One of best here, Worked great for me.

Comment: This is a very idiomatic solution, worked like a charm for me, thanks!

Comment: This one!, I need to update the order of some table, this one saved me.

Answer (score 33):

instead of this

```
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1200 WHERE name = 'Bob';
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1200 WHERE name = 'Jane';
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1200 WHERE name = 'Frank';
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1200 WHERE name = 'Susan';
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1200 WHERE name = 'John';
```

you can use

```
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1200 WHERE name IN ('Bob', 'Frank', 'John');
```

Comment: I like this one.

Answer (score 11):

maybe for someone it will be useful

for Postgresql 9.5 works as a charm

```
INSERT INTO tabelname(id, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'text for col4'),
    (DEFAULT,1,4,'another text for col4')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
    col2 = EXCLUDED.col2,
    col3 = EXCLUDED.col3,
    col4 = EXCLUDED.col4
```

this SQL updates existing record and inserts if new one (2 in 1)

Comment: As i can see, id is pk for the table as per your query.Suppose there are 2 or more columns considered as pk(Composite key)...In that case what should be the correct way to check the conflict.

Answer (score 9):

Camille's solution worked. Turned it into a basic PHP function, which writes up the SQL statement. Hope this helps someone else.

```
    function _bulk_sql_update_query($table, $array)
    {
        /*
         * Example:
        INSERT INTO mytable (id, a, b, c)
        VALUES (1, 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
        (2, 'a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
        (3, 'a3', 'b3', 'c3'),
        (4, 'a4', 'b4', 'c4'),
        (5, 'a5', 'b5', 'c5'),
        (6, 'a6', 'b6', 'c6')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
        a=VALUES(a),
        b=VALUES(b),
        c=VALUES(c);
    */
        $sql = "";

        $columns = array_keys($array[0]);
        $columns_as_string = implode(', ', $columns);

        $sql .= "
      INSERT INTO $table
      (" . $columns_as_string . ")
      VALUES ";

        $len = count($array);
        foreach ($array as $index => $values) {
            $sql .= '("';
            $sql .= implode('", "', $array[$index]) . "\"";
            $sql .= ')';
            $sql .= ($index == $len - 1) ? "" : ", \n";
        }

        $sql .= "\nON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \n";

        $len = count($columns);
        foreach ($columns as $index => $column) {

            $sql .= "$column=VALUES($column)";
            $sql .= ($index == $len - 1) ? "" : ", \n";
        }

        $sql .= ";";

        return $sql;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Execute the code below to update n number of rows, where Parent ID is the id you want to get the data from and Child ids are the ids u need to be updated so it's just u need to add the parent id and child ids to update all the rows u need using a small script.

```
 UPDATE [Table]
 SET column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM Table WHERE IDColumn = [PArent ID]),
     column2 = (SELECT column2 FROM Table WHERE IDColumn = [PArent ID]),
     column3 = (SELECT column3 FROM Table WHERE IDColumn = [PArent ID]),
     column4 = (SELECT column4 FROM Table WHERE IDColumn = [PArent ID]),
 WHERE IDColumn IN ([List of child Ids])
```

Answer (score 5):

Execute the below code if you want to update all record in all columns:

```
update config set column1='value',column2='value'...columnN='value';
```

and if you want to update all columns of a particular row then execute below code:

```
update config set column1='value',column2='value'...columnN='value' where column1='value'
```

Comment: what if different value in different row? for example
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1125 WHERE name = 'Bob';
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1200 WHERE name = 'Jane';
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1100 WHERE name = 'Frank';
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1175 WHERE name = 'Susan';
UPDATE staff SET salary = 1150 WHERE name = 'John';

Answer (score 5):

## UPDATE 2021 / MySql v8.0.20 and later

The most upvoted answer advises to use the `VALUES` function which is now **DEPRECATED** for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax. With v8.0.20 you get a deprecation warning with the VALUES function:

```
INSERT INTO chart (id, flag)
VALUES (1, 'FLAG_1'),(2, 'FLAG_2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id), flag = VALUES(flag);
```

> [HY000][1287] 'VALUES function' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use an alias (INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) AS alias) and replace VALUES(col) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause with alias.col instead

### Use the new alias syntax instead:

- [official MySQL worklog](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=13325)
- [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO chart (id, flag) 
VALUES (1, 'FLAG_1'),(2, 'FLAG_2') AS aliased
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag=aliased.flag;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the list of values to update in an Excel spreadsheet with **config_value** in column **A1** and **config_name** in **B1** you can easily write up the query there using an Excel formula like

`=CONCAT("UPDATE config SET config_value = ","'",A1,"'", " WHERE config_name = ","'",B1,"'")`

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO tablename
    (name, salary)
    VALUES 
        ('Bob', 1125),
        ('Jane', 1200),
        ('Frank', 1100),
        ('Susan', 1175),
        ('John', 1150)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE salary = VALUES(salary);
```

Comment: Hi, the question asks for a way to update multiple rows whereas the code you shared is for inserting multiple rows.

Comment: this is the best solution in my opinion

Comment: @UtsavBarnwal This is an INSERT command, but for rows where there is a match on PRIMARY or UNIQUE keys (in this case 'name') then MYSQL will do an UPDATE command. With VALUES() used to take the value from the INSERT data or 'salary' would be updated with the column data already in the db.

Comment: @tristanbailey thanks for the explanation. I just tried it with a complex query, it worked perfectly. Kudos to jay10

Answer (score 1):

just make a transaction statement, with multiple update statement and commit. In error case, you can just rollback modification handle by starting transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;
/*Multiple update statement*/
COMMIT;
```

(This syntax is for MySQL, for PostgreSQL, replace 'START TRANSACTION' by 'BEGIN')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a easy smart hack

Answer (score 0):

Try either multi-table update syntax

Try it copy and SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id int, name varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE #temp2 (id int, name varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #temp (id, name)
VALUES (1,'abc'), (2,'xyz'), (3,'mno'), (4,'abc')

INSERT INTO #temp2 (id, name) 
VALUES (2,'def'), (1,'mno1')

SELECT * FROM #temp
SELECT * FROM #temp2

UPDATE t
SET name = CASE WHEN t.id = t1.id THEN t1.name ELSE t.name END
FROM #temp t 
INNER JOIN #temp2 t1 on t.id = t1.id
 
select * from #temp
select * from #temp2

drop table #temp
drop table #temp2
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `table name` SET `field name` = 'value' WHERE `table name`.`primary key`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update several rows at a time, the alternative is [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement):

- database complies a **query pattern** you provide the first time, keep the compiled result for current connection (depends on implementation).
- then you updates all the rows, by sending **shortened label of the prepared function** with different parameters in SQL syntax, instead of sending entire `UPDATE` statement several times for several updates
- the database parse the **shortened label of the prepared function**  , which is linked to the pre-compiled result, then perform the updates.
- next time when you perform row updates, the database may still use the pre-compiled result and quickly complete the operations (so the first step above can be omitted since it may take time to compile).

Here is [PostgreSQL example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-sql-prepare.html) of prepare statement, many of SQL databases (e.g. MariaDB,MySQL, Oracle) also support it.

Answer (score 0):

There have two another way :

[one:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75627308/7707781)

```
UPDATE `table_name`                                                             
SET                                                                
       `desc`   = CASE                                    
                    WHEN (`id_one`='1' AND `id_tow`='1') THEN '22222'                                                               
                    END                                                          
WHERE  (`id_one`, `id_tow`) IN ( ('1', '1') );
```

[two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750086/7707781)

```
 UPDATE table_name
   SET field_to_update = CASE concat(key1, key2) 
                WHEN concat(1,1) THEN field_value1 
                WHEN concat(2,1) THEN feild_value2 
                ELSE feild_to_update
                END
   WHERE concat(key1, key2) IN ( concat(1, 1) , concat(2, 1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` on MySQL causes the auto increment id to skip values, which may be acceptable. I prefer to use this approach instead.

```sql
CREATE TABLE config
    (`config_name` varchar(255), `config_value` varchar(255))
;
    
INSERT INTO config
    (`config_name`, `config_value`)
VALUES
    ('name1', NULL),
    ('name2', NULL),
    ('name3', 'value3'),
    ('name4', 'value4'),
    ('name5', 'value5')
;

UPDATE config
JOIN (select 'name1' as config_name, 'value1' as config_value
     union all
     select 'name2', 'value2'
     union all
     select 'name4', 'updated value4'
     union all
     select 'name5', 'updated value5'
     ) x on x.config_name = config.config_name
   SET config.config_value = x.config_value;
```

Alternatively, you can use temporary tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `foo` (`id`, `bar`) VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b');
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `foo_tmp` LIKE `foo`;
INSERT INTO `foo_tmp` (`id`, `bar`) VALUES (1, 'c'), (2, 'd');
UPDATE `foo` f INNER JOIN foo_tmp ft ON f.id = ft.id SET f.bar = ft.bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0 or later you can do this with [JSON Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html):

```
UPDATE config
JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    '[
        {"config_name":"name1","config_value":"value"},
        {"config_name":"name2","config_value":"value2"}                
    ]',
    '$[*]'
    COLUMNS(
        config_name varchar(45) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci PATH '$.config_name',
        config_value varchar(100) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci PATH '$.config_value'
    )
) config_values ON config.config_name = config_values.config_name
SET config.config_value = config_values.config_value;
```