# How can I save objects in bulk with django 1.6

Tags: python, django-1.6

I am looking for a way to update multiple objects more efficiently than calling `.save()` on each of them.

I have code, which uses `.filter()` to load objects. Then it communicates with an external service, in order to decide what need to be done with each object. Finally I have a list of objects with updated values, which I need to save.

This code works, but is too slow:

```
for o in l: o.save()
```

Searching for suggestions I have so far found `.bulk_create()` and `.update()`

`bulk_create` works great for new objects. But replacing above loop with `model.objects.bulk_create(l)` produces `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:`, probably because it is trying to create new objects rather than updating existing objects.

Using `.update()` does not appear to be applicable to my use case either, because it will update all objects in the set with the same value. In my case I have computed a different value for each of the objects, that I need to save.

Is there a faster solution than calling `.save()` on each object?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a `has_changed` flag in an object when it is modified, then only saving the objects where `has_changed` is True.

This is under the assumption that not all the objects are always modified though. If all the objects always change, this is not the solution.

Comment: I don't call `save` on all the objects I retrieved. I run through all the objects once doing some calculations in memory. Those objects, which are modified by this calculation gets appended to a new list. The list I want to save in the end contains only objects, which have been modified.

Comment: ahhh okay, well I'll keep pondering it in the back of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Django can't do this, because (in general) your database can't do this. There's no single SQL statement to update different rows with different values. (Special exceptions like using `CASE...WHEN` aren't likely to help here.)

If many or most of the objects were new, you might track which and create those with `bulk_create`; otherwise, iterating and doing `save()` is probably your best bet.

You might consider parallelizing the procedure using threads, especially if there's significant latency communicating with the external service.

Comment: It might not have to be a single SQL statement. Sending multiple SQL statements back to back and deferring handling of replies, could be much faster than handling them completely sequential.

Comment: Any reason django couldn't have a generic `bulk_save` method based on `CASE WHEN` like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20255203/3476849

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround:

```
class CASE(object):
    def __init__(self, field_name, objects):
        self.field_name = field_name
        self.objects = objects

    def __unicode__(self): return self

    def as_sql(self, qn, connection):
        sql = [ 'CASE id' ]
        params = []
        for o in self.objects:
            sql.append('WHEN %s THEN %s')
            params.append(o.pk)
            params.append(getattr(o, self.field_name))
        sql.append('ELSE')
        sql.append(qn(self.field_name))
        sql.append('END')
        return (' '.join(sql), params)

model.objects.update(value=CASE('value', l))
```

It is not pretty, but as far as I can tell, it does produce correct and efficient SQL as long as I am just updating one text field.

Comment: I feel I shouldn't accept my own answer because it is so narrow, that even though it may be a suitable workaround for my particular case, it doesn't answer the general version of the question as I stated it. In order to achieve that, it would at the very least have to automatically apply to all applicable fields. Also my workaround is a bit of a hack. And I'd rather rely on a build-in feature than constructing my own `as_sql` method.

Comment: A cleaner implementation of the above would use `django.db.models.expressions` instead of my very hacky approach.