# How to add values to a column for multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
EN ENAME      CITY           SALARY        DNO JOIN_DATE
- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
E1 Ashim      Kolkata         10000          1
E2 Kamal      Mumbai          18000          2
E3 Tamal      Chennai          7000          1
E4 Asha       Kolkata          8000          2
E5 Timir      Delhi            7000          1
```

My attempt:

```
insert into table2(join_date) 
values('&date');
```

I know that update clause can be be used to update but at a time one row is possible

Are there any query such join_date column can be updated with a single query  but for multiple rows?

Comment: What does the documentation for your database software say?

Comment: i don't know how to view as i m new to dbms

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Insert or Update? And why do you think you can update only one row with one query? It all depends on the filter you place

Comment: I guess is what u want to achieve?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query

Comment: update table usefull buddy. why it isn't ? update table without where condition will effect to all rows.

Comment: I want to insert date values to the join_date columns

Comment: Google is a good resource for beginners.  There are tutorials out there for pretty much every database system in use.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly update `JOIN_DATE` by this query

```
UPDATE table2 
set JOIN_DATE = date;
```

or

```
UPDATE table2 
set JOIN_DATE = date
where JOIN_DATE IS NULL;
```

date is given by user.
such as

```
UPDATE table2 
set JOIN_DATE = '24-02-2014';
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE table2 set JOIN_DATE = date`

You need to make sure the `date` variable is set. A where clause will allow you to choose which row(s) get updated. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Edit for Oracle

Comment: Bro ur query is working but all the rows are getting the same value.but i want to add different values for different rows  with such a query that can be used to add different values to the join_date column

Comment: Updated. You just need to use a where clause. The syntax is in the link.

Comment: Example `UPDATE table2 set JOIN_DATE = date WHERE EN = 'E1'`