# 3 arrays in one foreach loop insert in database

Tags: php, html, loops, mysqli, foreach

So i have a page that looks like this (After i filled it in)

[image: How the page looks]

And i have a database table that looks like this:

[image: what the database looks like]

Now, after i press the button: `"Add to summary"`, i would like the info to be inserted in the database like this:

[image: What the database should look like]

I did this before but then with 2 arrays, and now i have 3. Code it worked with:

```
    $train_id = $_POST['train_id'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        foreach (array_combine($train_id, $user_id) as $train_id => $user_id){
            $update_axle = $database->summary_add($train_id, $user_id);
        }
```

But now, i have `['summary_name']` extra.

What my table looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="summary_name[]" id="summary_name" required placeholder="Enter summary name">
<input type='hidden' name='user_id[]' value='<?php echo $_GET['user_id']?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='train_id[]' value='<?php echo $selected_train['train_id']?>'>
```

These give the correct value.
Then when you press the `Add to summary` button, you will go to the page that should insert the values:

Function:

```
function create_summary($train_id, $summary_name, $user_id) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO summary "
        . "(summary_id, user_id, summary_name, train_id)"
        . "VALUES (summary_id, :user_id, :summary_name, :train_id) ";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $_POST['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sth->bindParam(':summary_name', $_POST['summary_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':train_id', $_POST['train_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sth->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Don't insert/update/whatever in loops. It's a bad idea. [You can do multiple updates in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query). Inserts too.

Comment: Hmm, il take a look at it @Andrew

Comment: I can't figure it out..