# Adding multiple rows and catching non inserted ones

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a table with two (relevant) columns : `reference`, and `count`. I want to do a query that would add multiple references, and does the following :

- if a reference I'm adding doesn't exist, insert a new row with this reference and its count
- if a reference I'm adding does already exist in the table, don't insert a new row, just increase the count for this reference.

I've thought about doing something like that :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (reference, count) VALUES ($ref1, $newquantity1), ($ref2, $newquantity2), ($ref3, $newquantity3) //etcaetera 

// Here I'd catch the ignored rows ( = the references that are already in the table)

UPDATE table
SET count = CASE reference 
   WHEN '.$reference_already_present_1.' THEN 'count = count + '.$newquantity1.'
   WHEN '.$reference_already_present_2.' THEN 'count = count + '.$newquantity2.'
    //and so on for every reference already in the table
END
WHERE reference IN($reference_already_present_1, $reference_already_present_2);
```

(This update query came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20255203/4348534))

The thing is, I don't know if I can catch the ignored rows from the first insertion, and if so, how to do it. Is it possible ?

If not, how else could I achieve what I need ?

(If it's any relevant, I'm using php, pdo and mysql).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.  But first, you need a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_table_reference on table(reference);

insert into table(reference, count)
    values($reference, $count)
    on duplicate key update count = count + values(count);
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure, isn't the last line supposed to be `on duplicate key update count = count + values(**$**count);` ?

Comment: @Malimalo . . . You could do either `count = count + $count` or `count = count + values(count)`.  The `values()` function returns the value for the field used in the update.