# PHP - Update and set multiple variables with different WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Need to update different values with different WHERE.

```
$facebook = $_POST["facebook"];
$twitter = $_POST["twitter"];
$instagram = $_POST["instagram"];

$sql = "UPDATE footer SET link='$facebook' WHERE name='Facebook' AND SET link='$twitter' WHERE name='Twitter' AND SET link='$instagram' WHERE name='Instagram'";
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE footer SET link='$facebook' WHERE name='Facebook' AND SET link='$twitter' WHERE name='Twitter' AND SET link='$instagram' WHERE name='Instagram'";
 is not working

Comment: I need to update facebook,twitter and instagram at once

Comment: Why don't do 3 queries?
otherwise try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20255203/5368495

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping :)

Comment: Sidenote: update uses only one SET / WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with case expression:

```
$sql = "UPDATE footer SET link = case when name='Facebook' then '$facebook'
                                      when name='Twitter' then '$twitter' 
                                      when name='Instagram' then '$instagram'
                                  end
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: This would have been a better answer if the errors that the OP made in their syntax were explained. As in UPDATE only uses one SET and one WHERE clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: @JohnDoe You're welcome John.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right, was in a hurry:) usually I'm posting an explanation