# Are there any Joomla methods to update multiple database rows with single query?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have no problem to update single row using methods `JDatabaseDriverMysqli->updateObject(..)` or `JDatabaseQueryMysqli->update(...)->set(...)->values(...)`, but then you create separate query for each row. Are there Joomla methods which would allow multiple rows updates with single query?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Joomla methods to insert new rows and then adding

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE,
a=VALUES(a),
b=VALUES(b),
c=VALUES(c);`

at the end of Joomla constructed insert query.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27593831/1353644