# How do I update several rows in mysql using one query

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a cart and it has several items, am trying to update the inventory so that all items in the inventory are updated when a buyer checks out..so it would subtract all the hardcover, softcover and ebooks from inventory depending on the purchases..I know how to make it work when I just need to update one record the question is how do I update several rows...
Here is my current sql..

```
UPDATE inventory INNER JOIN cart ON inventory.isbn = cart.isbn 
SET inventory.num_hardcover = inventory.num_hardcover - cart.hardcover_purchased 
WHERE inventory.isbn=cart.isbn
```

Comment: Similar question was already been asked, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query

Comment: Is this query working at all? My first thought would be to update the value based on a subquery, i.e. `UPDATE inventory i SET num_hardcover = num_hardcover - (SELECT sum(hardcover_purchased) FROM cart c WHERE c.isbn = i.isbm)` I'm not at my database server, I may be able to test later.

Comment: @Bill Karwin...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it oout

```
UPDATE inventory 
INNER JOIN cart ON inventory.isbn=cart.isbn 
SET inventory.num_hardcover =inventory.num_hardcover-cart.hardcover_purchased,
    inventory.num_softcover=inventory.num_softcover-cart.softcover_purchased 
WHERE inventory.isbn=cart.isbn
```

Comment: You don't need the `WHERE` clause, since it's the same as the `ON` clause.

Comment: I don't see the difference between this query and the original one in the question. They both update all rows that match the `JOIN` condition. The only difference is that this one updates multiple columns, but your question was about updating multiple rows. Are you confused about the difference between rows and columns?

Comment: @Barmar yeah I wasn't sure about how to go about editing multiple rows...But I got it...thanks

Comment: I still don't understand the answer. This edits the same rows as the query in the original question. The original query edits 1 column, this edits 2 columns.