# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in Laravel 6?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I've been having race issues recently and I'm wondering if eloquent has any function for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

I tried using `updateOrCreate()`, but it seems like under the hood it does a `select` and then an `update` or `insert`.

Comment: Laravel has no native UPSERT support. I've created a package for it: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert

Comment: This looks like a duplicate to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863015/laravel-insert-or-update-multiple-rows

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I've just used it and it works great. Thank you for it, you should change the comment to an answer.