# Bulk insertOrUpdate in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

How can we insertOrUpadate()  bulk data? I have around 60,000 data in bulk so doing a loop insert is very slow and also the bulk data is ever increasing.

Comment: Could you please show more info? What have you already tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel insert or update multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863015/laravel-insert-or-update-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to prepare MySQL insert statement for inserting multiple rows and run this query as a single insert query.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name(a,b,c) VALUES
(1,2,3),
(4,5,6),
(7,8,9);
```

Please refer [SqLBulkInsert](https://thedebuggers.com/mysql-bulk-insert-update-using-php/) post for more detail.