# How to update multiple records using peewee

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I'm using Peewee with Postgres database. I want to know how to update multiple records in a tabel at once?
We can perform this update in SQL using [these commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query), and I'm looking for a Peewee equivalent approach.

Comment: Have you tried Model.update() method?

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering about performance. I've recently started learning and I red [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.insert_many) that multiple times inserting a single item is wrong and I couldn't find a method similar to insert_many

Answer (score -6, accepted):

ORMs usually dose not support bulk update and you have to use custom SQL, you can see samples in this [link](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html?highlight=execute_sql#sql-functions-subqueries-and-raw-expressions) (db.excute_sql)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `insert_many()` function:

> Insert multiple rows at once. The rows parameter must be an iterable
>   that yields dictionaries. As with insert(), fields that are not
>   specified in the dictionary will use their default value, if one
>   exists.

Example:

```
usernames = ['charlie', 'huey', 'peewee', 'mickey']
row_dicts = ({'username': username} for username in usernames)

# Insert 4 new rows.
User.insert_many(row_dicts).execute()
```

More details at: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.insert_many

Comment: But this is inserting new items, I'd like to update existing records.

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah Then use a single `.update()` as Gordian mentioned. It runs as a single transaction, not several separate update operations.

Comment: Thank you. yes eventually I changed my pipeline to use `update` method