# How to update a column twice with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with these values:

```
Name       |  id
----------------
Blue guy   |  20
Green girl |  10
```

The `id` column is a unique value. What I want is to update blue guy id to 10 and in that same query I want to update green girl id to 20. My current `SQL` query is:

```
UPDATE colorpeople SET id = 20
WHERE name = 'Blue guy';
```

Where can I specify to update the green girl to?

Comment: Take a look at this question and the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query

Comment: logically it's two update statements because it's two different values with different conditions attached. But you can combine it into one statement as per the link given just above. It only really scales to two or three values though, if you need to do it for large numbers of rows it'll get unwieldy.

Comment: Typically, this kind of thing is done in a 3-step transaction - 1. Update 20 to x. 2. Update 10 to 20. 3. Update x to 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
UPDATE colorpeople 
SET id = (case 
           when name = 'Blue guy' then 10   
           when name = 'Green girl' then 20 
           else id = id 
           end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below script :

```
ALTER TABLE colorpeople DROP CONSTRAINT PK_colorpeople

UPDATE colorpeople SET ID = 10 WHERE Name = 'Blue guy'
UPDATE colorpeople SET ID = 20 WHERE Name = 'Green girl'

ALTER TABLE colorpeople ADD CONSTRAINT PK_colorpeople PRIMARY KEY /* CLUSTERED */ (ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
INSERT INTO colorpeople id VALUES 10, 20
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this uses a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE colorpeople 
    SET id = (case when name = 'Blue guy' then 10
                   when name = 'Green girl' then 20
              end)
    WHERE name in ('Blue guy', 'Green girl');
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to update a unique key that already exists

```
UPDATE colorpeople SET id = -20 WHERE naam = 'Blue guy';
UPDATE colorpeople SET id = -10 WHERE naam = 'Green girl';
UPDATE colorpeople SET id = -id WHERE naam in ('Blue guy', 'Green girl');
```