# MySQL cross-table update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `users` table and a `sales` table.

The `users` table has columns `id` and `annual_plan_length`, `monthly_plan_length`.

Example user row:

`id | annual_plan_length | monthly_plan_length`

`55 | 0                  | 0`

The `sales` table has columns `id`, `user_id`, `product`

Example `sales` rows:

`id | user_id | product`

`1 | 55       | monthly`

`2 | 55       | annually`

I am trying to write a query to update the users plan length column according to how many purchases they've made using the `sales` table.

Here's what I got so far:

```
function updateLength($product, $column) {
  global $emdb;

  mysql_query("UPDATE users
            JOIN sales
            ON sales.user_id = users.id
            SET users.`".mysql_real_escape_string($column)."` = count(sales.id) GROUP BY sales.user_id
            WHERE sales.product = '".mysql_real_escape_string($product)."'", $emdb);

}

updateLength('monthly', 'annual_plan_length');
updateLength('annually', 'monthly_plan_length');
```

This query doesn't work, but with your help, this should end up putting a 1 on the columns `monthly_plan_length` and `annual_plan_length` for the user ID 55.

Ps.: I know PDO is better but it's not used yet for this client's project.
Ps.: Syntax error near `GROUP BY`

Comment: At least fix the SQL injection on .$column in the  query

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that this can be an issue given that the input only comes from my own code. Can you tell me how this can be injected?

Comment: "This query doesn't work" Do you get a error?

Comment: injecting with  `= 0 --` or with  `= 0 #` would be fun there because -- and # are valid mysql comments.

Comment: Says I have a syntax error near `GROUP BY`

Comment: I feel like I should be putting GROUP BY at the end, but doesn't seem like I can put the SET clause after the WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes GROUP BY should be after the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can use `GROUP BY` in end your query. I see a problem on your query because you want to update every user that have a same product but with diferent values of purchases.

You need to remove `GROUP BY` .

Maybe it help you:

`UPDATE users
JOIN sales
ON sales.user_id = users.id
SET users.annual_plan_length = (SELECT count(user_id) FROM sales WHERE user_id = 1 WHERE sales.product = 'monthly');`

Because the edit should be 6 characters, here's what I did: I put the paren at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the results in the sub-query at first, and then update the data for all users.

Try this query:

```
UPDATE (SELECT `user_id`, SUM(IF(`product` = 'monthly', 1, 0)) AS `monthly`, SUM(IF(`product` = 'annually', 1, 0)) AS `annually` FROM `sales` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `user_id`) AS `s`
INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `u`.`id` = `s`.`user_id`
SET `u`.`annual_plan_length` = `s`.`annually`, `u`.`monthly_plan_length` = `s`.`monthly`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not use `JOIN` in an update statement. Instead, use a nested `SELECT` query to get a count:

```
UPDATE table SET field = (SELECT COUNT(some_other_filed)
FROM other_table WHERE your_field = condition)
```

Comment: "you can not use JOIN in an update statement" Wrong you can use a JOIN in a update query.

Comment: @Odyssey1111 How would you use that more specifically with my question?