# Sum multiple rows and update by group_by a column. (Laravel elqoeunt)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to SUM rows in MySQL table then merge and update. I'm trying to sum all the duplicate payments in a day. I will post my existing query but there are some limitations.

**Example:**

```
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| id |    date    | merchant_id | investor_id | payment |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 | 27/05/1989 |           4 |           7 |    1000 |
|  2 | 27/05/1989 |           4 |           7 |    1200 |
|  3 | 28/05/1989 |           4 |           7 |    1500 |
|  4 | 28/05/1989 |           4 |           7 |    1000 |
|  5 | 28/05/1989 |           5 |           8 |    1000 |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

**Expected result:**

```
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| id |    date    | merchant_id | investor_id | payment |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 | 27/05/1989 |           4 |           7 |    2200 |
|  3 | 28/05/1989 |           4 |           7 |    2500 |
|  5 | 28/05/1989 |           5 |           8 |    1000 |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

**I tried this loop.**

```
foreach ($existing_payments as $key => $payment) 
{
    ParticipentPayment::where('payment_date',$payment->payment_date) ->update(['payment' => \DB::raw("payment+$payment->payment"]);
}
```

Problem 1. I can only update one column at a time.

Problem 2. I'm programmatically looping through the rows and updating value, because of that if there is no duplicate value then the row not getting updated. I have to write another query to update. To delete existing query also.

Problem 3. It works well only for two payments.

**Is there any possible solution in laravel eloquent merge(with sum) multiple rows and update?**

Comment: Can you add some sample data before and after you run the queries?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me an edit. Please check the tables, now I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Should all of a day's payments get merged? Regardless of `merchant_id` and `investor_id`?

Comment: Only if merchant_id and investor_id equal, example table updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$delete = [];
$payments = ParticipentPayment::selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(`id` SEPARATOR ',') `ids`")
    ->selectRaw('SUM(`payment`) `sum`')
    ->groupBy('date', 'merchant_id', 'investor_id')
    ->get();
foreach($payments as $payment)
{
    $ids = explode(',', $payment->ids);
    if(count($ids) == 1) continue;
    ParticipentPayment::whereKey($ids[0])->update(['payment' => $payment->sum]);
    $delete = array_merge($delete, array_slice($ids, 1));
}
ParticipentPayment::destroy($delete);
```

Comment: yeah, Good solution, but update query inside the loop,

Comment: How do you mean that? Do you want a single `UPDATE` query for all payments?

Comment: In the above solution, if there are 1000s of payments, then the update query will run 1000s time and destroy query will run. 

Maybe we can add all the $ids to an array and destroy altogether. 
Maybe a similar method for the update also?
what you think about that.

Comment: I improved the `DELETE` query in my answer. For `UPDATE` queries this is [a lot more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20255203/4848587) and probably not worth the effort.